# Can a Video Autoplay with No Controls, but still be able to start/stop

Tags: controls, autoplay

When you setup up a video to autoplay and have no controls, the viewer is unable to stop / restart the video...

Is there an option to make it so that the controls are not viewable but the viewer can still click the video to stop and restart?

Answer (score 0):

You could have an overlay over the video that could play and stop the video.